# Removing divs with javascript failure at startup

Tags: javascript, css, visibility

I have this div:

```
<div class="container2"> 
    <div class="message"> 
         <h1> Bla bla.</h1> 
    </div> 
    <div class="circle"> 
         Animations here 
    </div> 
</div>
```

That I want it to not show when the page loads. The idea is to bring it up later.
So I have this javascript code, that is located inside the `<body>`:

```
<script>
    document.getElementsByClassName('container2').style.display = "none";
</script>
```

But when the page loads, the div is there.

Comment: So why not set it's initial display to `none`?

Comment: It's getElement***s***ByClassName for a reason (not `getElementByClassName`). Use `querySelector()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **[`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)** method returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names and you're trying to call the `style` property on the returned `array-like` object when the `style` is a property of `HTMLElement`.

I suggest the use `querySelector()` instead in this case :

```
document.querySelector('.container2').style.display = "none";
```

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  document.querySelector('.container2').style.display = "none";
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container2">
  <div class="message">
    <h1> Bla bla.</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="circle">
    Animations here
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Add `display: none;` to the div either in your CSS:

```
.container2 {
    display: none;
}
```

Or in the element directly:

```
<div class="container2" style="display: none;">
```

This will hide the `div` completely until the `display` value is changed.

---

Then use JavaScript to display it later:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("container2")[0].style.display = "block";
```

Comment: Thanks but i wanted to change it later, so i wanted to do this with javascript and not have it hardcoded.

Comment: @user1584421 I know you've used Zakaria's answer. But just so you are aware.. You still use JavaScript to display the `div` afterwards. View the small edit of my answer! Also setting `display: none;` would be better UX in this case, as it will never be visible. Whereas using Zakaria's answer, the `div` will be visible to the user at first, and then it will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify the DOM before it's finished loading using this function.

You have two options.

You can add in your css :

```
.container2{display:none}
```

And then make it visible when certain conditions are met.

Or you can wait for the DOM to be completely loaded using jQuery ready() function, and then execute your function.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    $('.container2').css("display","none");
});
```